# How can I redirect with a controller with id in ASP .NET MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello so what I'm trying is to create an id for Privacy Page which is in Home Controller,
now it looks like this

```
public IActionResult Privacy(string? id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home", new { id = "1234"});
        }
```

In the Program.cs file(I don't have startup.cs file) this is how the route config looks like:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

EDIT: So what I want is when I access the Privacy Page it should redirect me to https://localhost:7204/Home/Privacy/1234, but it throws an error saying that: This page isn't working

should I add another MapControllerRoute?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. The code looks fine there. Explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I'm trying is to create an id for Privacy Page which is in Home
> Controller

If you want to use RedirectToAction,you can create a new action, do you want like below?

```
        public IActionResult PassIdToPrivacy(string? id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Privacy", "Home", new { id = "1234" });
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

url:
https://localhost:7133/home/PassIdToPrivacy?id="aa"

result:

[image]